# How to download and setup dependencies for a Julia project that is in development?

Tags: julia

I am trying to download and install dependencies for a Julia project that's not in the package registry. It has a manifest and project file. How do I get all of the packages it depends on to download at once using the Julia Package manager?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Download the source: `git clone https://github.com/RandomUser/Unregistered.jl`
2. Activate the project: `pkg> activate Unregistered.jl`
3. Ensure any dependencies are installed: `pkg> instantiate`

Once the package is set up, you can use the package normally.
You can load the package:

```
julia> using Unregistered
```

Or even run its test suite:

```
pkg> test
```

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, here is a "pure" Julia version of what @David Varela suggested.

After substituting `<url-to-project>` and `/some/local/path` this "just works" in the REPL or similar:

```
using Pkg
Pkg.GitTools.clone("<url-to-project>", "/some/local/path")
cd("/some/local/path")
Pkg.activate(".")
Pkg.instantiate()
# Pkg.precompile() # optional
```

Comment: I have a follow up on this. So this all works fine and dandy, however, if I close Julia, and re-open it, do I need to do `activate .` again? (given I am in the appropriate folder).

Answer (score 1):

Preparation (optional):

1. Create a new folder somewhere and `cd` into it.
2. Start Julia with `julia --project=.`

Now the actual downloading/installing:

3. Develop the project locally: `pkg> dev --local https://github.com/RandomUser/Unregistered.jl`

This will clone the unregistered project into a local subfolder `dev/Unregistered` and will install all the required dependencies.

If the unregistered project is a Julia package, you can now simply `using Unregistered`. If you want to work on `Unregistered.jl` itself you can `pkg> activate dev/Unregistered` to work in the project environment.